# Color non empty cell of an entire column

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I would like to color the non empty cell of a column in a sheet.
I would prefer to do it with conditionnal formating

When i set it up without vba it looks like :
[image: wanted formating]

I tried

```
.Columns(7).FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression,_
     Formula1:="=G:G<> """"").Interior.Color = MyFormating
```

The range is ok, but the formula doesn't works

Comment: Try: `.Columns(7).FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression,_
     Formula1:="=G1<> """"").Interior.Color = MyFormating`

Comment: Works fine! Thanks. But why G1 ? Excel unwrap as a cell reference ?

Comment: See my answer for an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `.Columns(7).FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression,_ Formula1:="=G1<> """"").Interior.Color = MyFormating`

A brief explanation:

Conditional formatting will assume the formula provided applies to the first cell (top-left) in the range the condition is applied to. Excel will then adjust the formula for each cell. (as long as the references are not absolute)

So if your condition applies to range `G:G`, Excel will use the conditional formulas as follows:

For `G1`: `.Columns(7).FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression,_ Formula1:="=G1<> """"").Interior.Color = MyFormating`

For `G2`: `.Columns(7).FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression,_ Formula1:="=G2<> """"").Interior.Color = MyFormating`

For `G3`: `.Columns(7).FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression,_ Formula1:="=G3<> """"").Interior.Color = MyFormating`

and so on..

This applies in both directions, so that if you applied the condition on multiple columns (say `G:L`), you would get:

For H1: 
`.Columns(7).FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression,_ Formula1:="=H1<> """"").Interior.Color = MyFormating`

For `I1`:
`.Columns(7).FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression,_ Formula1:="=I1<> """"").Interior.Color = MyFormating`

and so on